chaining api calls on terminal using result of previous call
I have to run several api calls, using output of a call in next call.
step1out=$(out=$(curl ....) && step2out=$(curl...using step1out) && curl -v -k --location --request GET 'https://.....?param1=${step2out}'

step1out is result of first call, which I use in second call to fetch step2out,and it works as expected. But when I try to use step2out in third call, it doesnt work as expected.
If I run third call in isolation using value step2out then it works.
What am I missing?

I do not know what you are missing, but I am missing debugging details (and a [mre] )

BTW: you are missing a ) (somewhere after: $(out=$(... , and before the first &&)

Use quotation marks (") rather than apostrophes (') around the third expression (GET)

step1out=$(out=$(curl ....)) && step2out=$(curl...using "$out") && curl -v -k --location --request GET 'https://.....?param1="$step2out"

In your 3rd call, you are explicitly prohibiting the expansion of the variable step2out. Why are you using single quotes? What did you expect from this?
